# Gradle build failed: Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved

Tags: spring, gradle

I am building a RESTful web service with Spring by following [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) guide. I am using gradle to build the app but my build is failing.

I used the "build gradle" command on a Windows 10 machine.

This is the gradle code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

I am getting the following error:

Execution failed for task ':bootJar'.

> Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved

Comment: I have same error. In My PC project build successfully. but when try to run command "grade bootjar or build" return above error ..

Answer (score 107, accepted):

When building a multi-module project which includes a module outside of the springboot project, then the module's `build.gradle` must contain:

```
bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}
```

Comment: The file gradle.build mentioned in this post is reversed. It should be build.gradle. Indeed adding the above in build.gradle for a multi-module project resolves the issue

Comment: I had this issue out of the sudden and your solution helped indeed. However, I have two library modules and only the last one requires it. This is my hierarchy:  `[application-module]->[working-library-module]->[non-working-library-module]` and I have no explanation for this inconsistency. Both library modules are applying the java-library Gradle plugin. So I guess, the second library is considered outside of the springboot project, but both are in the same multi-module project. Do you have any idea why that might be the case?

Answer (score 40):

I ran into this error when I used kotlin and misplaced the `main` method.

Wrong:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Application {
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        runApplication<Application>(*args)
    }
}
```

Fix (moved `main` out of `Application`):

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

Comment: Totally saved me! I'm new to Kotlin and I've made the very same mistake.

Comment: In another instance, the java class marked with @SpringBootApplication did not have a `static` modifier in the main method

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. It really helped me.  - Kotlin beginner

Answer (score 13):

So, you can configure it. Pls try:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'com.example.WebApplication'
```

Comment: How to do the same for spring kotlin, since the main class name does not have a main function.

Answer (score 9):

According to https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/, the library's `build.gradle` (that uses Spring) should use Spring Boot Plugin without applying it (apply false):

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0' apply false
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'java'
}
```

That eliminates the need for:

```
bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}
```

Also, for the Spring Boot application that uses the library, we need to specify `scanBasePackages` with the library's group:

```java
package com.example.multimodule.application;

import com.example.multimodule.service.MyService;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example.multimodule")
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

  private final MyService myService;

  public DemoApplication(MyService myService) {
    this.myService = myService;
  }

  @GetMapping("/")
  public String home() {
    return myService.message();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: This saved me after few hours of building nonstop. New to multi module gradle project and after trying various fixes for the `className` the `apply false` to my plugins fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

With the **org.springframework.boot** Gradle plugin version 2.6.2.

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.0'
}
```

I had similar issue.

> Execution failed for task ':bootJar'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':bootJar' property 'mainClass'.
> Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved

Now depending on the version of the springframework boot plugin you have to define the main class value on following way.

**[SpringFramework 2.3.12 and older](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.12.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-configuring-main-class)**

```
springBoot {
  mainClassName = 'com.example.ExampleApplication'
}
```

**[SpringFramework 2.4.0 and newer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable-configuring-main-class)**

```
springBoot {
  mainClass = 'com.example.ExampleApplication'
}
```

[Release notes mentioning change of the property](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes#spring-boot-gradle-plugin)

Comment: Specifying the main class like you mentioned fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

in my case, (using [Kotlin for writing springboot demo](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/spring-boot-restful.html)) it was caused by the src folder, the main class file did not locate under src/main folder.
besides, I've clean everything up and restart IDE.
As @Zaziro mentioned, I've also token a try, but without any luck.
But there're articles mentioned config [mainClassName](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-main-class),

and after comparing with src code in Github that different, it's not about any version of any package.

Wish u luck :-)

Answer (score 2):

As @Zaziro mentioned, it's possible to define a configuration.

This site describes the different kinds of configuration very well: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-main-class#gradle

IF YOU ARE USING KOTLIN:

Be aware that your class name changes. You need to append your mainClassName with "Kt".

example: "com.example.Application" -> "com.example.Application**Kt**"

Answer (score 1):

If we're using the Spring Boot Gradle plugin and Kotlin you can use the snippet below:

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.7"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.31"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.31"
}

...

springBoot {
    mainClass.value("com.mycompany.MyApplication")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have multi module project, and for me it was adding

```
bootJar { enabled = false }
```

to the main ***build.gradle***, since there is no main method there.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to follow the instructions at https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/ that has a CommandLineRunner in the application. The code inside the CommandLineRunner would only run if I wrapped that bean *and* the main method in the class. I could get tests to run but not via the command line. I was able to get around this by using a companion object:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class TestApplication {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            runApplication<TestApplication>(*args)
        }
    }

    @Bean
    fun commandLineRunner(ctx: ApplicationContext): CommandLineRunner {
        ...
    }
}
```